# How to use Amplify without configure?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

I'm using AWS Amplify with Appsync as follows:

```
const cfg = {
  aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint: 'some-endpoint',
  aws_appsync_region: 'us-some-region',
  aws_appsync_authenticationType: 'API_KEY',
  aws_appsync_apiKey: 'some-key'
}
Amplify.configure(cfg)
const someMutation = await getMutationFromTheEther()
const allEvents = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(someMutation))
```

Works great, but now I'm wrapping the logic between timeouts and batches and stuff, I'm using it from a Lambda function.

In the AWS SDK you can do a request without configuring globally, like the following:

```
const s3 = new S3(awsConfig)
const data = await s3.getObject(someParams).promise()
```

Is it possible to do it like that with Amplify, without having to call the global object `Amplify`?

I tried `const graphQlApi = new API(cfg)` but all I got is `TypeError: aws_amplify_1.API is not a constructor`